# Adding a 'select all' function to drop down GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface, select, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu GUI and can't figure out how to add a "select all months" option.

The problem is quite complex as the '$group' output is being used for a number of different things such as a get-childitem filter, file path with a variable, and a filtering and organising system using individual file names and ordering them by month. So is there a way to add an option like. Numbers 01-12. Or is there a more sophisticated GUI which allow for easier multi selection of numbers?

```
[array]$DropDownArrayItems = "","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"
[array]$DropDownArray = $DropDownArrayItems | sort

# This Function Returns the Selected Value and Closes the Form

function Return-DropDown {
    if ($DropDown.SelectedItem -eq $null){
        $DropDown.SelectedItem = $DropDown.Items[0]
        $script:Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
        $Form.Close()
    }
    else{
        $script:Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
        $Form.Close()
    }
}

function SelectGroup{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")


    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

    $Form.width = 300
    $Form.height = 150
    $Form.Text = ”Select Filter Month”

    $DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,10)
    $DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

    ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
     [void] $DropDown.Items.Add($Item)
    }

    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

    $DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
    $DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
    $DropDownLabel.Text = "Select Month:"
    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)

    $Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
    $Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $Button.Text = "OK"
    $Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown})
    $form.Controls.Add($Button)
    $form.ControlBox = $false

    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()


    return $script:choice
}

$Group = $null
$Group = SelectGroup
while ($Group -like ""){
    $Group = SelectGroup
}
write-host $Group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an option is easy:

```bsh
[array]$DropDownArrayItems = "", "01", "02", "03",
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", 
"11", "12", 'Select all months'
```

To have an `array` of `integers` as output one can do:

```bsh
if ($Group -eq 'Select all months') {
    1..12 | ForEach-Object { '{0:00}' -f $_ }
}
```

Thiw will output:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, but I don't quite get where to put the :if ($Group -eq 'Select all') {
    1..12 | ForEach-Object { '{0:00}' -f $_ }
}  It just spits out 'Select all' when I write-host, I am very new to Powershell If you hadn't guessed

Comment: Replace `write-host $Group` with `if ($Group -eq 'Select all months') {...`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox does not support multi select why not try System.Windows.Forms.Listbox 
and set the mode to  system.windows.forms.selectionmode (None, One, MutiSimple, or MultiExtended)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to have an option for "all" then add a button or array entry in the combobox that returns that and closes the form?

If you want the ability to multiselect specific entries e.g. 1,3,6,7,8 then I'd use a listview instead with multiselect as you can then return them as an object using $ListViewBox.SelectedItems.Text or similar.